# Prism VM binding with View within Page code behind

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin Forms & PCL

I saw a lot of examples and snippets About binding VM with View in the Page.Xaml

using this block

```
xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
      prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
```

And what if I want to bind the view model within the page code behind (Page.cs).

Answer (score 6):

You can get access to ViewMode from code behind is simply by typecasting your binding context

```
var pageViewModel = (PageViewModel)this.BindingContext;
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

That case you have to pass the both parameter on class instantiated because you are have required two parameter in constructor.Try the below code.

```
 public Page()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = new PageViewModel(Navigation,PageDialogService);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just can new the viewmodel and set it to the BindingContext.

```
public Page()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = new MyViewModel();
}
```

==== EDITED ====

If your viewmodel is with parameter that need to dependency inject and you want to resolve it correctly.

App.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    ...
    Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType<IMyViewModel, MyViewModel);
    ...
}
```

Page.xaml.cs

```
public Page()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var viewModel = Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve<IMyViewModel>(((App)Application.Current).Container);
    this.BindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

Comment: so what can I do in case that the view model parameters are
          PageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService,IPageDialogService pageDialogService)

Comment: In this case, you need to resolve the ViewModel using dependency injection. You can make your App class static accessible. Then call to App.Container.Resolve([your viewmodel type]). But before this can work, you will need to Register the viewmodel into the Container by calling Container.RegisterType([your viewmodel type], viewmodel class)

Comment: could i still can use it in spite of my container of type Dryioc.Icontainer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

I removed from page.xaml

```
     xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
  prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
```

and inside the code Behind (page.cs)

i added

```
    public Page()
    {
          InitializeComponent();
          this.BindingContext = new pageViewModel(null,null);
    }
```

and it worked for me

Comment: But your NavigationService and PageDialogServer will be null in the viewmodel

Comment: i agree with you that in some pages the _navigationservice has a value and in other ones it is null but still work for both cases , i wish you try and explain it me.